# Not getting error message on "offline" mode

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

I'm working on the application that has a `patch` method to send data to the database.
I'm using a `toPromise()` method to get the call back and do whatever needs to be done depending on the response, however, if I turn off network connection, and submit my form, I still get the "OK Message" even thou clearly there was an 'error' because there is no connection.

What am I doing wrong?

*PS: If the formSendStatus is false, it should display the error message.*

**Here is my service:**

```
return this.http.patch(url, JSON.stringify(data),
            { headers: this.httpOptions.headers,
              responseType: 'text'
            }
);
```

**And my component**

```
return this.hs.edit(data).toPromise().then(
    () => {
        this.showDialog = true;
        this.hs.formSendStatus.next(true);
        setTimeout( () => {
            this.router.navigate(['information']);
        }, 2000 );
    },
    (e) => {
        this.showDialog = true;
        this.hs.formSendStatus.next(false);
        setTimeout( () => {
            this.showDialog = false;
        }, 2000 );
    }
).catch(
    (e) => {
        this.showDialog = true;
        this.hs.formSendStatus.next(false);
        setTimeout( () => {
            this.showDialog = false;
        }, 2000 );
    }
);
```